# Creating a SOLR index for activity stream or newsfeed

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am trying to index the activity feed of a social portal am building. The portal allows users to follow each other to get updates from the people they follow as an activity feed sorted by date.

For example, user A will be following users B, C, D, E & F. So user A should see all the posts from B, C, D, E & F on his/her activity feed.

Let's assume the post consist of just two fields.
1. The text of the post. (text_field)
2. The name/UID of the user who posted it. (user_field)

Currently, I am creating an index for all the posts and indexing the `text_field` & `user_field`. In scale, there can be 1,000,000+ posts. A user may follow 100s if not 1000s of users. What will be the best way to create an index for this scenario?

1. Should I also index a person followers, so that its quickly looked up and then pass it to a second query for getting the posts of all those users sorted by date?
2. What is the best way to query the index consisting of all these posts, by passing the UID of all the users that are followed? Considering this may be in 100's or more.

**Update:**
The motivation for using Solr for the news feed was mainly inspired by [this detailed slide](http://www.quentinsuire.com/presentations/a-news-feed-with-elasticsearch/#/) and my brief discussion with [OpenSocial](https://www.getopensocial.com/) team.

When starting off with a social portal, `Fan out on write` seems an overkill and more expensive. However `Fan out on read` is better. Both the slide and the OpenSocial team suggested using a search backend for `Fan out on read`. [The slide](http://www.quentinsuire.com/presentations/a-news-feed-with-elasticsearch/#/) mentioned above also have data on how it helped them.

At present, the feed is going to be flat and only sort criteria will be the date(recency). We won't be considering relevance or posts from more closer groups.

Comment: I don't know if you figure it out since you post it. You can work it out with Solr with two cores (one of the network and one of the feeds). In the network core you can store userid (string) and producers (string). In the feeds core you can store the atomic feeds with userid as a facet and feed details in a flat way (actor_id,actor_objectType,actor_displayName) then query the network for producers and then query the feeds with those producers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of abstract, but I will do my best here. Based on what you mentioned, I am not sure if Solr is really the right tool for the job here. You can still have Solr for full text search, but I am not sure about generating a news feed from it in this scenario. Remember that although Solr is pretty impressive, it is a search engine. I will pretend that you will stick with Solr for the rest of the post, keep in mind that we are trying to put a square peg through a round hole here though.

Here are a few additional questions you should think about.

- You will probably want to add a timestamp of the post to the data element
- You need to figure out how to properly sort the results. Is it in order of recency? Or based on posts that the user is more likely to interact with?
- If a user has 1000+ connections, would he want to see an update from every one of them in the main feed? Or should posts from a closer group of friends show up higher?

Here are some comments about your questions:

1) If you index person's followers, it may be hard to keep up. I am assuming followers are going to be changing often and re-indexing in this scenario would not really be practical.

2) That sounds more on par, but again, you need to figure out the sorting. You can get a list of connections for the user, then run a search for top posts from all of them.

Comment: I have updated my question with some more details. The feed will not consider relevance or closeness to the post owner. We will have a flat feed sorted by date. I got the suggestion to use search backend when using a feed that is `Fan-out on read`. I have added this in little more detail in the update of the question.